# How to cleanly convert between lists and ListT monad transformers?

Tags: list, haskell, monads, monad-transformers, non-deterministic

I am currently writing a project where I make a heavy use of `ListT` monad transformer. When using plain lists, implementing nondeterminism is very easy. However once I had to convert my code to `ListT`, it got much more complicated <sup>1</sup>.

As a simple example: converting from `[a]` to `ListT a` actually requires composing two functions:

```
conv :: (Monad m) => [a] -> ListT m a
conv = ListT . return
```

Though it's simple, I am surprised it's not already there.

**Questions:**

- Is there some better way to handle nondeterminism where a monad transformer is needed?
- Are there any techniques / libraries for converting cleanly back and forth between lists and `ListT`?

---

<sup>1</sup> The exact reasons are quite complicated, so I don't really want to elaborate too much on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there are any libraries for this; `conv` is an incredibly simple function, after all, and the other way around is just `runListT`.

`conv` is similar to the `liftMaybe` often desired when using `MaybeT`:

```
liftMaybe :: (Monad m) => Maybe a -> MaybeT m a
liftMaybe = MaybeT . return
```

I would recommend naming it something along the lines of `liftList`.<sup>1</sup>

As far as a better monad transformer for nondeterminism goes, I recommend taking a look at the [logict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict) package, based on Oleg's `LogicT` transformer, which is a continuation-based backtracking logic monad with [some helpful operations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic-Class.html). As a bonus, since `[]` is an instance of `MonadLogic`, those operations also work on lists.

---

<sup>1</sup> Interestingly, we can define a function that generalises the pattern of `conv` and `liftMaybe`:

```
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

choose :: (Foldable t, MonadPlus m) => t a -> m a
choose = F.foldr (\a b -> return a `mplus` b) mzero
```

This will probably make your code quite confusing, so I don't recommend using it :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that `conv` is a simple function. I'm just surprised that it's not already there. There are hardly any utilities in the `ListT` module which makes me feel like I reinvent the wheel. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question a few months later because I was wondering something similar to this.  So I came up with the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.List


-- | Minimal implementation: either joinLift or joinT
class (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => MonadTransJoin t m | m -> t, t -> m where
    joinLift :: (Monad m', Monad (t m')) => m' (m a) -> t m' a
    joinLift = joinT . lift

    joinT :: (Monad m', Monad (t m')) => t m' (m a) -> t m' a
    joinT = (>>= (joinLift . return))


instance MonadTransJoin MaybeT Maybe where
    joinLift = MaybeT
    joinT = (>>= maybe mzero return)

instance MonadTransJoin ListT [] where
    joinLift = ListT
    joinT = (>>= foldr mcons mzero)
        where mcons x xs = return x `mplus` xs
```

So far so good—and my `joinT` method for the `ListT`/`[]` pair looks like it has something to do with ehird's `choose`.

But the problem with this is that there is actually no uniform interface between a monad transformer and the monad whose behavior it endows to its base monad.  We have `MaybeT :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a` and `ListT :: m [a] -> ListT m a`, but OTOH we have `StateT :: (s -> m (a, s)) -> StateT s m a`.  I don't know if there's a way to get around this—it certaindly requires